# Cannot use Unity on 18.04

Tags: unity, 18.04

Ever since I updated to 18.04 I cannot use the Unity desktop. I log into the Unity desktop, the background appears for a second, no desktop, then it shows up the lightdm screen again. I can log into a guest session of Unity (and omg love it and miss it, such a great desktop). I have reset CCSM. I have removed gnome, unity, reinstalled and still cannot get to the Unity desktop. What can I do short of a full reinstall?

Thank you for your time and answers!

Comment: You should try going to a tty, (ctrl+alt+F3 on lightdm, ctrl+alt+F4 on gdm3), logging in, removing or moving .config/dconf/user & then rebooting.. May help may not. I'd probably use full path for command so something like this, username is replaced by your username. `mv /home/username/.config/dconf/user  /home/username/.config/dconf/user.bak && reboot` and  see if better.  If you didn't want to back up then just  `rm /home/username/.config.dconf/user  && reboot`

Comment: Hey, so going to ~/.config/dconf then changing the file called "user" to my user name, then rebooting, worked! Thanks! If you wanted to put that as an answer I would like to accept it.